# Conditional equations with with one curly bracket in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations

How would I code something like this

[image]

I've got the code

```
    \begin{equation}
       L = 
        \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if $i = j$ and $deg_j \neq 0 $} \\
            stuff & \text{if $(i, j) \in E$} \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
```

but where `stuff` is I want to use `-\frac{1}{\sqrt{deg_ideg_j}}` and where `L` is I want the Laplacian symbol `\mathcal{L}`. Whenever I try to put them in I get an error message that says "Missing $ inserted" and I'm not exactly sure what it means, or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). You don't need the `$` in _stuff_. You are already in math mode at that time.  The `$` are required if you have math _within_ `\text{}` as then you are in text mode, not math mode.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Even without the $ before it still comes up with the same error. I've just updated it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when I complete your code in the obvious way. Could you please provide a complete document i.e. add the document class and required preamble etc. so that when you copy-paste-compile the code, it gives the error you want help with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L} =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if $i = j$ and $deg_j \neq 0 $} \\
    -\frac{1}{\sqrt{deg_i deg_j}} & \text{if $(i, j) \in E$} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases]

Comment: This works great for cases, as opposed to the dcases*, mentioned above. Thank you for your help as well!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use a `dcases*` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package) for the job at hand. This environment differs from the `cases` environment in two important ways: (i) the math part (before the `&` separator) will be typeset in display-style math, and (ii) there's no need to wrap the text-material (after the `&` symbol) in `\text` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "dcases*" environment
\begin{document}
\[
\widehat{L}(u,v) = 
\begin{dcases*}
   1                         & if $u=v$ and $d_v\ne 0$ \\
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_u d_v}} & if $(u,v)\in E$ \\
   0                         & otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you change your example to give the output the OP wants? Then I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @cfr - In view of the fact that the OP has accepted your answer in the meantime, I'd rather not change the code above. :-)

Comment: I can see my mistake now, I wasn't using the correct package. Only had amsmath. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @BriKil - If you're going to use the `cases` environment, there's no need to load the `mathtools` environment. The `mathtools` environment is needed only if you want to use the `dcases*` environment.

Comment: @Mico Fair enough.

Comment: @cfr - I've upvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: I upvoted yours. But yours is better, so I have an excuse. @BriKil I added `\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}` automatically. It isn't required for the answer I posted to work. `amsmath` is enough.